# Does Power Query make process of importing data to Power Pivot model faster than importing right from PP?

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

I've got few huge tables in SQL database. And there is a model created in Power Pivot which calls these tables right from Power Pivot. When i try to refresh the model it takes hours, so i have got a question if it's faster to import data to Power Query first, and right after that to create a model. Or there is no difference in execution time?